# Delete uploaded picture in profile (from i.stack.imgur.com hosting)

Tags: support, images, profile-picture

An old uploaded pic of me is still saved on i.stack.imgur.com, although it is not used. Google has indexed it, which I don't want any more, and they will keep it while it is there.

How can I delete an old profile picture from i.stack.imgur.com?

Comment: I *think* that's what you meant, but please double-check.

Comment: yes thank you. As far as i know, there is no way to delete content on i.stack.imgur.com

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137057/158100

Comment: I'm not sure if imgur's own [removal request form](http://imgur.com/removalrequest) is applicable for the i.stack.imgur.com domain.

Comment: MSE duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250344/158100

Comment: See Adam Lear's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202719/172965) or possibly use the [Imgur Removal Request Form](http://imgur.com/removalrequest).

Comment: Hi, I did a mistake during the upload of a picture and sent the wrong picture with sensitive informations. I tried to send a ticket but anyway to speed up the process to delete the picture like a phone support or something like that?

Answer (score 10):

As in the [cross-site duplicate target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250344/delete-uploaded-image) [from Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250344/delete-uploaded-image):

> Flag it for moderator attention, explain why you need it removed. Specifically, explain why just editing it out or deleting the post isn't good enough.
>
> If you convince the moderator handling the flag that you're not crazy, they'll pass it on to one of us & we'll nuke it.

That doesn't seem to apply to your situation, *however* you could try flagging one of your own posts explaining the issue.

---

**Suggested Solution:**

As [animuson mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250346/255735) in the same Q&A as before:

> You can send a removal request directly to Imgur. I doubt they would
> deny a user's request to have an image with personal information
> purged from their records.

[Send a removal request directly to Imgur](https://imgur.com/removalrequest), but again explain your situation in full (specifically that the image is attributed to you and you would like it removed).

I suppose you could take *either* path (custom mod flag or reporting to Imgur), but if I were you I'd report directly to Imgur as it is likely to get your image removed faster.

Comment: contact with imgur should be the answer +1

Comment: What if the image is "Russia"?